# Android activity transitions - Window.excludeTarget() prevents transitions of child views

Tags: android, android-transitions, appbar, android-appbarlayout

I'm playing around with the new `Transition Api` and would like to achieve a nice transition between two activities. Both activities contain an `AppBar` with a tabbed `ViewPager`.

When I was running the transition the first times, the `AppBar` was faded out and in again between the two activity transitions, so it looked like it was blinking:

[image]
[image]

To solve that I tried to exclude the `AppBar` from the activity transition by calling `transition.excludeTarget()`:

```
// in onCreate() of the calling activity
Transition transition = new Fade();
transition.excludeTarget(mAppBarLayout, true);
getWindow().setExitTransition(transition);
getWindow().setReenterTransition(transition);

// in onCreate() of the called activity
Transition transition = new Fade();
transition.excludeTarget(mAppBarLayout, true);
getWindow().setEnterTransition(transition);
getWindow().setReturnTransition(transition);
```

This code solved the blinking problem but introduced a new one: there is no crossfade animation for the `ViewPager Tabs` anymore:

[image]

This is how both layouts look like in generell:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:background="@color/toolbar_background"
        >
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/toolbar_icons"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            />
        <com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout.SmartTabLayoutLight
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
     />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Is there a way to exclude a view/layout from the transition animation but to include its children? I've tried to add the `ViewPager Tabs` by calling `transition.addTarget(mTabs);`, but it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You should of only exclude your toolbar instead of whole AppBarLayout.

```
transition.excludeTarget(toolbar, true);
```